# Error inflating class <unknown> - app crashes

Tags: java, android

In an Android app that I developed, the app crashes when I move to a certain activity. I saw that many people encountered a similar problem before, but none of the former answers solve my problem.

Here's the relevant code:

### StillsActivity.java

the code crashes on the last line of this snippet

```
public class StillsActivity extends SpatialFilteringActivity {

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "Stills";

    private Uri mURI;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Mat mImToProcess = new Mat();
    private Mat mImGray = new Mat();
    private Mat mFilteredImage = new Mat();

    private SeekBar mSeekBarSpatial;
    private SeekBar mSeekBarIntensity;
    private SeekBar mSeekBarAlpha;
    private SeekBar mSeekBarBeta;
    private TextView mTextViewSpatial;
    private TextView mTextViewIntensity;
    private TextView mTextViewAlpha;
    private TextView mTextViewBeta;
    private MenuItem mSelectedItem;


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
            data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mURI = data.getData();
                if (mURI != null) {
                    try {
                        mBitmap = Util.getBitmap(this, mURI);
                        mImageView.setImageBitmap(Util.getResizedBitmap(mBitmap,
                                1000));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stills);

// APP CRASHES HERE

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        Button loadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadButton);
        loadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i(TAG, "onClick event");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an image"), SELECT_PICTURE);

            }
        });

        mSeekBarSpatial = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSpatial);
        mTextViewSpatial = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sigmaSpatialTextView);
        setSeekBar(mSeekBarSpatial, mTextViewSpatial, getResources().getString(R.string.stringSpatial), MyImageProc.SIGMA_SPATIAL_MAX);
        mSeekBarIntensity = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarIntensity);
        mTextViewIntensity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sigmaIntensityTextView);
        setSeekBar(mSeekBarIntensity, mTextViewIntensity, getResources().getString(R.string.stringIntensity), MyImageProc.SIGMA_INTENSITY_MAX);

        mSeekBarAlpha = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarAlpha);
        mTextViewAlpha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alphaTextView);
        setSeekBar(mSeekBarAlpha, mTextViewAlpha, getResources().getString(R.string.stringAlpha), MyImageProc.ALPHA_MAX);
        mSeekBarBeta = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarBeta);
        mTextViewBeta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.betaTextView);
        setSeekBar(mSeekBarBeta, mTextViewBeta, getResources().getString(R.string.stringBeta), MyImageProc.BETA_MAX);
    }

// etc.
```

### SpatialFilteringActivity.java

```
public class SpatialFilteringActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SpatialFiltering";

    //menu members
    private SubMenu mResolutionSubMenu;
    private SubMenu mCameraSubMenu;

    //flags
    private Boolean mSettingsMenuAvailable =false;

    protected static final int SETTINGS_GROUP_ID = 1;
    protected static final int RESOLUTION_GROUP_ID = 2;
    protected static final int CAMERA_GROUP_ID = 3;
    protected static final int DEFAULT_GROUP_ID = 4;
    protected static final int COLOR_GROUP_ID = 5;
    protected static final int FILTER_GROUP_ID = 6;
    protected static final int STILL_GROUP_ID = 7;

    private MyJavaCameraView mOpenCvCameraView;

    private CameraListener mCameraListener = new CameraListener();

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    private String[] mCameraNames = {"Front", "Rear"};
    private int[] mCameraIDarray = {CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT, CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_BACK};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spatial_filtering);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (MyJavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.Java_Camera_View);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraIndex(CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_ANY);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(mCameraListener);
        Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i(TAG, "onClick event");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                        "/sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
                mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
                addImageToGallery(fileName, SpatialFilteringActivity.this);
                Toast.makeText(SpatialFilteringActivity.this, fileName + " saved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
    //etc.
```

### activity_stills.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="il.ac.tau.adviplab.iplab2_hn.StillsActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loadimage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/load_button"
        android:id="@+id/loadButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBarSpatial"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sigmaSpatialTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sigmaSpatialTextView"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/sigmaSpatialTextView"
        android:text="@string/stringSpatial"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarSpatial"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBarIntensity"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sigmaSpatialTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sigmaSpatialTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sigmaSpatialTextView"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/sigmaIntensityTextView"
        android:text="@string/stringIntensity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarIntensity"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBarIntensity"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBarIntensity"/>


    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarAlpha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sigmaIntensityTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alphaTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/alphaTextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/alphaTextView"
        android:text="@string/stringAlpha"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarAlpha"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sigmaIntensityTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sigmaIntensityTextView"/>
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBarBeta"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alphaTextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/alphaTextView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/alphaTextView"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/betaTextView"
        android:text="@string/stringBeta"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarBeta"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBarBeta"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/seekBarBeta"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

note: the @drawable/loadimage is 1000*978 pixels, if that matters

### Logs

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{il.ac.tau.adviplab.iplab2_hn/il.ac.tau.adviplab.iplab2_hn.StillsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
  at il.ac.tau.adviplab.iplab2_hn.StillsActivity.onCreate(StillsActivity.java:73)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
  at il.ac.tau.adviplab.iplab2_hn.StillsActivity.onCreate(StillsActivity.java:73) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
  at il.ac.tau.adviplab.iplab2_hn.StillsActivity.onCreate(StillsActivity.java:73) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:666)
  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3969)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
  at il.ac.tau.adviplab.iplab2_hn.StillsActivity.onCreate(StillsActivity.java:73) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: The inflate exception is not actually the problem, but really comes from another deeper issue in your layout that is then wrapped in an InflateException. A common issue is an out of memory exception when trying to inflate an imageview loading a drawable resource. If one of this resources has a high pixel resolution it would take a lot of memory causing then an inflate exception.

So basically verify that the pixel resolution in your drawables images are just the minimum necessary for your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow background image size

For Supported device

```
    LDPI:
    Portrait: 200x320px
    Landscape: 320x200px
    MDPI:
    Portrait: 320x480px
    Landscape: 480x320px
    HDPI:
    Portrait: 480x800px
    Landscape: 800x480px
    XHDPI:
    Portrait: 720px1280px
    Landscape: 1280x720px
```

Comment: so if I'll resize the image, it should make the difference?

Comment: I'm positive that it should. Try out setting some launcher icon for that imageview and check if it still shows an error. If it does then you know its because of the image. Try [Batch Drawable Import](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin) to import a image in proper sizes as per the devices.

Comment: well, I tried to load the ic_launcher instead (I have multiple ic_launchers with different sizes), it still crashes with the same error :(

Comment: Could you please post the complete code of your Activity or at least of onCreate()

Comment: Yes, I just updated the original post. thanks for helping :)

Comment: What's SpatialFilteringActivity ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157235/discussion-between-deep-lathia-and-noamgot).